# When describing my personal opinions, should I use "one thing I was sure", "was that" or "is that"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, be

When describing my personal thoughts back in a few years ago.

Should I use:

```
One thing I was sure though, is that ...
```

or

```
One thing I was sure though, was that ...
```

To me, it sounds more correct to use "was", because it's some thoughts from the past. But I understand when describing a fact, such as the "sun goes up from the east", you should use the present tense.

If I still hold the thought I had back then, would it be OK to use "is" instead of "was"?

Answer (score 1):

> One thing I was certain of was that ....
>
> One thing I was pretty sure of was that ...

Keep your prepositions where they belong, and keep your tenses straight.

Answer (score 1):

- Of one thing I was sure: the sun would rise in the morning.
  Or:
  One thing I was sure of is that the sun would rise in the morning.
  Or:
  One thing I was sure of was that there was no milk left in the fridge.